# Where is PagedCollectionView in Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight-5.0, pagedcollectionview

Where is PagedCollectionView in Silverlight 5?  I'm trying to convert a SL3 app to 5 but can't find PagedCollectionView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is on `System.Windows.Data` (`C:\Program Files (x86)\MicrosoftSDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client\System.Windows.Data.dll`)